# How to fix Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined?

Tags: javascript, next.js

[image]I have the above error message and i am not sure about what cause this to happen.
On the below code snippet i am fetching some data from a file named Data.js located on my root folder.
When i run my the app i receive the mentioned error message but when use the same data without importing for an external file it works perfectly. which is not making much sense, Can someone tells me what i am doing wrong please? Thanks in advance.
Services.js

```
import { FaCircle, FaShoppingCart, FaLaptop, FaLock } from 'react-icons/fa'
import  { serviceLinks } from '../../../Data'

const data = serviceLinks;
console.log(data);
// const serviceLinks = [
    
//     {
//         title:'Haircut',
//         text:'All dependencies are kept current to keep things fresh.'
       
//     },
//     {
//         title:'Barberos',
//         text:'You can use this design as is, or you can make changes!'
        
//     },
//     {
//         title:'Color',
//         text:'Is it really open source if its not made with love?'
        
//     }, 
// ]

const icons = [
    FaShoppingCart, FaLaptop, FaLock
    
]
function Services () {
    
    return (
        <section className="page-section" id="services">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="text-center">
                    <h2 className="section-heading text-uppercase">Services</h2>
                    <h3 className="section-subheading text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="row text-center">
                    { data.map((service,idx) => {
                        const Icon = icons[idx];
                        console.log(Icon)
                        return (
                            <div className="col-md-4" key={idx}>                        
                            <span className="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <FaCircle className="svg-inline--fa fa-circle w-16 fa-stack-2x text-dark" height={100} width={100} />
                                <Icon className="svg-inline--fa fa-shopping-cart fa-w-18 fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" fill="white" />
                            
                            </span>
                            <h4 className="my-3">{service.title}</h4>
                            <p className="text-muted">{service.text}</p>
                        </div>
                        )
                    })
                  
                    }
                </div> 
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
export default Services;
```

data.js

```
 const galleryLinks = [
    {
        title:'HairStyle',
        haircutName:'Afro',
        imgUrl:"assets/img/portfolio/fullsize/dr.cut_thebarbers_afro.jpg",
        imgUrl2:"assets/img/portfolio/thumbnails/dr.cut_thebarbers_afro.jpg",
    },
     {
        title:'Hairstyle',
        haircutName:'Blondo',
        imgUrl:"assets/img/portfolio/fullsize/dr.cut_thebarbers_blondo.jpg",
        imgUrl2:"assets/img/portfolio/thumbnails/dr.cut_thebarbers_blondo.jpg",
    },
    {
        title:'Hairstyle',
        haircutName:'Chica',
        imgUrl:"assets/img/portfolio/fullsize/dr.cut_thebarbers_chica.jpg",
        imgUrl2:"assets/img/portfolio/thumbnails/dr.cut_thebarbers_chica.jpg",
    },
    {
        title:'Hairstyle',
        haircutName:'Nino',
        imgUrl:"assets/img/portfolio/fullsize/dr.cut_thebarbershow_nino.jpg",
        imgUrl2:"assets/img/portfolio/thumbnails/dr.cut_thebarbershow_nino.jpg",
    },
    {
        title:'HairStyle',
        haircutName:'Wavy',
        imgUrl:"assets/img/portfolio/fullsize/dr.cut_thebarbershow_wavy.jpg",
        imgUrl2:"assets/img/portfolio/thumbnails/dr.cut_thebarbershow_wavy.jpg",
    },
    {
        title:'HairStyle',
        haircutName:'Blondo2',
        imgUrl:"assets/img/portfolio/fullsize/dr.cut_thebarbershow_blondo2.jpg",
        imgUrl2:"assets/img/portfolio/thumbnails/dr.cut_thebarbershow_blondo2.jpg",
    },   
    
]

  const serviceLinks = [
    {
        title:'study our themes',
        text:'Our themes are updated regularly to keep them bug free!',
        icons:"assets/img/logo/Hnet.com-image.svg",
    },
    {
        title:'Haircut',
        text:'All dependencies are kept current to keep things fresh.',
        icons:"assets/img/logo/clipper.svg",
    },
    {
        title:'Barberos',
        text:'You can use this design as is, or you can make changes!',
        icons:"assets/img/logo/barber_chair.svg",
    },
    {
        title:'Color',
        text:'Is it really open source if its not made with love?',
        icons:"assets/img/logo/hairstyle.svg",
    }, 
]

export { galleryLinks,  serviceLinks};
```

index.js

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.scss'
import Header from './src/components/Header'
import Services from './src/components/Services'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <Head>
        <title>Dr Cut TheBarber Show</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className="main">
       <Header />
       <Services />
      </main>

      <footer className="footer text-center">
        <a
          className="text-decoration-none text-dark"
          href="https://vercel.com?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Powered by{' '}
          <span className={styles.logo}>
            <Image src="/vercel.svg" alt="Vercel Logo" width={72} height={16} />
          </span>
        </a>
      </footer>
      </div>
    
  )
}
```

Comment: What does your file tree look like?

Comment: hi @code ,thanks for trying to help, what do you mean by file tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the way you are importing `Data.js`

Here is the source of the error:

```
const icons = [FaShoppingCart, FaLaptop, FaLock];
```

```
{data.map((service, idx) => {
            const Icon = icons[idx];
```

You basically have an array of 3 icons but your serviceLinks array length is 4 in your Data.js so at some point in the map you are doing `icons[3]` which returns `undefined` and causes the error.

Add an icon to your icons array to match your last serviceLink.

[Working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-forked-lmo2k?file=/pages/src/components/Services.js).